# Can .NET deserialize JSON object with Map[]?

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

We need to consume in .NET some web services, written in Java (or maybe PHP?) I believe, which return JSON objects. Originally, the JSON objects consisted entirely of String properties, or arrays of other JSON objects.

They've recently updated them though, and there are some properties on the JSON definitions defined in the `Swagger` documentation as so for example:

```
lockPriceByLockTerm (Map[string,BigDecimal], optional)
```

All of the other properties on all the various JSON classes are all defined either as

- `(string)`
- `(array[string])`
- `(OtherJsonObject)`
- `(array[OtherJsonObject])`

Originally I was going to be using the following code to deserialize the JSON into .NET classes with matching definitions:

```
Public Function FromJSON(Of T)(data As String) As T
    Dim rv As T
    Dim serializer = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(rv.GetType)
    Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data))
        rv = CType(serializer.ReadObject(ms), T)

        Return rv
    End Using
End Function
```

Will this code be able to handle those `Map[]` things though? What class/type do I need to make my corresponding property on my target class? I'm assuming it would be like a `Dictionary(Of Double, String)` or something... but I don't know if the `DataContractJsonSerializer` can even handle those.

I've done some basic serialization of objects TO JSON before, but this is my first time trying to deserialize FROM JSON.

Due to the way this project is running (hosted in a cloud-based system that gets downloaded to client machines) we can't really use any third-party DLLs. It needs to run strictly on the .NET Framework itself.

We're working in VB.NET on Framework 4.5.

Comment: what *are* "those Map[] things"?  that doesnt look like VB syntax

Comment: That is the way the properties are described in the Swagger documentation for the web service. I've added also the other defined property types used by all the classes.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

Comment: Our DLL is being attached to a custom form in a third-party cloud application. As far as I know, there is no way for us to attach other DLLs as well. We do not really have control over the end-users' run time environments other than knowing the Framework itself will be installed.

Comment: Hmm, actually, I ***may*** be able to, ... I need to play around with something else I just found. Do you know for sure JSON.NET will be able to handle those `Map[]` fields?

Comment: Ha! I figured out how to get supporting DLLs loaded into this cloud system, and am now using JSON.NET - successfully converts those Map things to Dictionary objects. Thanks @Vadim ~

Comment: @Vadim, if you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept and award the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) instead of the DataContractJsonSerializer (even though it probably could do the job)